# Deleting duplicated lines throughout sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So below is a copied part of my spreadsheet.  It should be connect then disconnect the next line.  But I have some duplicates here as you can see there is a pair of connects and disconnects in the first 4 lines. I'm basically trying to know what the easiest way I could go through all my cells and detect a pair of connects or disconnects then delete the bottom connect and the top disconnect as they are linked together.

```
5997998 D16 connect 2021-06-21 17:31:04.141+00
5997993 D16 connect 2021-06-21 17:30:43.708+00
5997996 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 17:30:20.106+00
5997979 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 17:28:08.268+00
5997906 D16 connect 2021-06-21 17:19:03.802+00
5997902 D16 connect 2021-06-21 17:18:43.226+00
5997905 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 17:18:19.939+00
5997883 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 17:16:09.056+00
5997812 D16 connect 2021-06-21 17:07:05.033+00
5997807 D16 connect 2021-06-21 17:06:43.875+00
5997808 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 17:06:20.145+00
5997793 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 17:04:08.07+00
5997685 D16 connect 2021-06-21 16:54:46.16+00
5997677 D16 disconnect  2021-06-21 16:52:07.01+00
5997604 D16 connect 2021-06-21 16:43:04.436+00
```

I would assume it would be possible with a macro but I'm not sure I just started using macros. Not sure if this is even possible just wanted to hear suggestions if any one has any.

Comment: Why a macro when built in functionality does the job? (`Data -> Data tools -> Remove Duplicates`)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that will delete them all except one connect and one disconnect.  I want to find the duplicate within every two rows if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you edit your question to let us know exactly what you want the end result to be?

Answer (score 1):

Scan down the sheet counting connects, scan up counting disconnects and deleting the duplicates where count > 1.

```vb
Sub RemoveDupl()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long, iCount As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' connects
    iCount = 0
    For r = 1 To iLastRow
       If ws.Cells(r, "C") = "connect" Then
           iCount = iCount + 1
           If iCount > 1 Then
               ws.Cells(r, "C") = "dupl"
           End If
       Else
           iCount = 0
       End If
    Next

    ' disconnects
    iCount = 0
    For r = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
       If ws.Cells(r, "C") = "disconnect" Then
           iCount = iCount + 1
           If iCount > 1 Then
               ws.Rows(r).Delete
           End If
       ElseIf ws.Cells(r, "C") = "dupl" Then
           ws.Rows(r).Delete
           iCount = 0
       Else
           iCount = 0
       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Duplicates with a Twist

- If the contents of two consecutive cells in the column (`Col` (`C`)) are equal, then if they contain one string (`CritLower` (`connect`)), then delete the lower row, and if they contain another string (`CritUpper` (`disconnect`)), then delete the upper row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveConnDupes()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "C"
    Const CritLower As String = "connect"
    Const CritUpper As String = "disconnect"
    
    ' Create references to the workbook and the worksheet.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Calculate last non-empty (not hidden) row ('lRow').
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Validate last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub ' No data (possibly hidden rows).
    
    Dim drg As Range ' Delete Range
    Dim dCell As Range ' Delete Cell
    Dim r As Long ' Row Counter
    
    For r = fRow To lRow - 1
        
        ' Compare the values in two consecutive cells
        ' (the current and the next).
        If ws.Cells(r, Col).Value = ws.Cells(r + 1, Col).Value Then
            
            ' Attempt (there could be a 'third' value) to create a reference
            ' to the cell ('dCell') whose row will be deleted.
            Set dCell = Nothing
            Select Case ws.Cells(r, Col).Value
            Case CritLower
                Set dCell = ws.Cells(r + 1, Col)
            Case CritUpper
                Set dCell = ws.Cells(r, Col)
            'Case Else
                'Set dCell = Nothing ' Redundant because it's already nothing.
            End Select
            
            ' Check if a reference to the cell has been created...
            If Not dCell Is Nothing Then
                ' ... If so, combine the cell into the Delete Range ('drg').
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = dCell
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, dCell)
                End If
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next r
            
    ' Check if any cells were combined...
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        ' ... If so, delete the Delete Range's entire rows.
        drg.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
        
End Sub
```